# Como internacionalizar uma aplicação Xamarin Forms (Shared Project)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, internacionalização

Como faço para criar resources em uma aplicação Xamarin Forms utilizando a metodologia de Shared Project?

Pesquisei por vários exemplos e todos eles explicam e possuem demos para as versões Portable. Tentei de todas as formas que vi à frente mas não consigo utilizar arquivos RESX no projeto compartilhado.

Alguém saberia como pode me auxiliar?

Agradeço a atenção

Comment: Sua dificuldade em encontrar exemplos talvez seja por que não é recomendado pela Xamarin:[Shared Projects are not recommended](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/#Globalizing_Xamarin.Forms_Code)

Comment: Amigo, não recomendo você utilizar a o Shared, para grande maioria dos projetos xamarin o PCL é a melhor escolha.